# How can I use the API that Chrome uses to check for the current version

Tags: selenium, browsers

I want to write a program that detects when a new version of Chrome has been released - and I want to use the same API that Chrome uses itself when it checks. This is so I can trigger some Selenium tests when the browser gets updated.

Other people have told me to use the blogspot page (http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com), but there's a lot of noise there from all the different versions tracked on that web page.

It seems it would be a lot more direct to find out the same way that Chrome finds out.

But I can't find a definition of the API - does anybody have any clues or hints? (PS, I can't just pull the exchange off the wire, as Chrome uses https so it is encrypted.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the API, but something more generic that would work for any browser would be to use a selenium test to execute some JavaScript.  navigator.appVersion gives you the browser version.

Comment: That would mean the Chrome client would have to have been updated already. I want to capture when a new version of Chrome is available from Google, whether or not any browser has been upgraded to it or not. That's why I need the API.

Comment: In the case of chrome, it is automatically updated every time you start up the browser.  It's actually difficult to get it to not update.